# Installing Orbot as a remote SOCKS server for other computers?

Tags: privacy, proxy

I installed Orbot on my Android device and I want to make it a remote SOCKS server so that other computers can connect to it.

The [TorFAQ – Tor Bug Tracker & Wiki](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorFAQ#CanIinstallToronacentralserverandhavemyclientsconnecttoit) suggests that for Tor on Windows, the user should edit Tor's directive file **torrc**. So I did the same thing with Orbot on my device. Here is the contents of my **torrc** file on Android:

```
SocksListenAddress 0.0.0.0
SocksPort 9050
SocksPolicy accept *
SafeSocks 1
Log notice stdout
ControlListenAddress 127.0.0.1
ControlPort 9051
CookieAuthentication 1
RelayBandwidthRate 20 KBytes
RelayBandwidthBurst 20 KBytes
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
TransListenAddress 127.0.0.1
TransPort 9040
DNSListenAddress 127.0.0.1
DNSPort 5400
HardwareAccel 1
SafeLogging 1
TestSocks 1
```

I added the first and third lines to the original file. However it doesn't work. The SOCKS server refuses the connection all the time.

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: From [ticket 5438](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/5438): *SocksListenAddress is deprecated but still used in default/sample torrc ... Replace this with "SocksPort 0" if you plan to run Tor only as a relay [...]* (I currently cannot check the full source as I'm behind a somehow restrictive firewall). Also, from the [Tor Manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en): *SOCKSListenAddress no longer has a purpose*

Comment: Thanks for the information but I can't find the line _SOCKSListenAddress no longer has a purpose_ in the manual, it's only available in Google cache. Also setting SocksPort to 0 would completely disable SOCKS connection to Tor.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I want to put my grandfathered unlimited data plan to good use.

Answer (score -1):

This solves the problem:

SocksPort 0.0.0.0:9050